# Select from Different Tables Where two clauses

Tags: mysql, sql, select

So I have 2 tables, the **users** and the **admin**. I have to select from both the firstname and surname like so:

`Users` table:

```
id firstname surname
1  Alex      Edison
2  Mary      Peterson
```

`Admin` table:

```
id firstname surname
1  Alex      Edison
2  George    Peterson
```

My selection should result 2 rows from Admin and Users tables of "Alex Edison" data (WHERE firstname = `Alex` AND surname = `Edison`).

Any idea of how can I achieve this?

Comment: Specify the expected result as well. And show us your current query attempt!

Answer (score 3):

Just use a `UNION`:

```
SELECT firstname, surname
FROM Users
WHERE firstname = 'Alex' AND surname = 'Edison'
UNION ALL
SELECT firstname, surname
FROM Admin
WHERE firstname = 'Alex' AND surname = 'Edison';
```

If you want to keep track of the source of each record, you could also select a computed column in each of the queries in the union.

Comment: thank you Tim! Can I use SELECT * to get all the records?

Comment: @zagzter Doing `SELECT *` on both queries in the union would only make sense if the number (and ideally type) of columns in both tables are the same.

Comment: ok! In case that I will have more columns in admin table? What should I do?

Comment: Just make sure that the columns you select in each query of the union line up, ideally with the types matching as well (if the types don't match, MySQL might be able to an implicit conversion to make them match).